# Trying to make a search with MKLocalSearch dans display results with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am new in swift and I try to create app for listing places to visit. I want to include a search on the map using MapKit. I was heldped with [this tutorial](https://www.thorntech.com/2016/01/how-to-search-for-location-using-apples-mapkit/) even it is a little old.

Here is my view controller "LocationSearchTable"

```
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems:[MKMapItem] = []
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil
    
    
    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }
}


extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        print("patate")
        guard
            let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            print("++++ \(self.matchingItems.count) ++++")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("\(self.matchingItems.count)  matchingitems")
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row].placemark
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = parseAddress(selectedItem: selectedItem)
        return cell
    }
}
```

It is almost the same as in the tutorial. I just update functions in the extension, and insert some "print" to check which part the code run.

when I run the app, an error occur when I start typing any letter in the search bar. The error is "UITableView dataSource returned a nil cell for row at index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x81e5bf003c01211e> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}.

I find some message with the same kind of error on stack overflow but I was unable to fix my own error.
Delegate and Datasource are defined in Storyboard (created automatically when using a table view controller).
matchingItems.countalways return 9 or 10, so I have answer to the search.
I think problems occur when unwrapping cell, and I cannot find the code to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by modifying Swift Language Version in Xcode to 5. I don't really understand what happened ...